# Почему браузер не отправляет Cookie с запросом на получение шрифта?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, frontend, шрифты

Есть шрифты, заданные в CSS с помощью @font-face. Все ресурсы лежат на отдельном сервере, куда осуществляется аутентификация посредством Cookie. Все работает здорово, кроме шрифтов - почему-то браузер, запрашивая их, не проставляет Cookie и вместо шрифта получаем 403.

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Пути к файлам шрифтов должны быть указанны верно.

([от сюда](http://dle-faq.ru/faq/css/10923-problema-s-font-face-i-403-oshibka.html)) Может так: в папке fonts нужно создать файл .htaccess с содержимым:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
```

([от сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056008/fontface-403-forbidden-error-in-zen-cart)) или это: нужно проверить файл .htaccess (если есть) - он может блокировать определенные файлы. Можно разрешить в нем расширения файлов, соответствующие файлам шрифтов. (например, eot,woff,ttf):

```
# все запретить
<FilesMatch ".*">
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# разрешить некоторые типы файлов:
<FilesMatch ".*\.(eot|ttf|woff)$">
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Это все здорово, когда имеешь доступ к настройкам сервера, который отдает контент. В нашем случае это Amazon CloudFront и такие вещи настроить точно не получится. Да и точно наличие файла .htaccess может повлиять на то, как браузер формирует запрос? Ведь формирует запрос клиент, а .htaccess на стороне сервера лежит

Comment: @andrey.ps2007
Настройки Amazon CloudFront проверяли? Может ссылка что подскажет: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/GettingStarted.html